# Finding a divergent sequence with exactly one convergent partial infinite limit

Tags: real-analysis

This is a challenge given by a teacher that said that he himself doesn't know an answer and doesn't know if it can be disproven.

The challenge is as follows: find a real sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ for which $PL(a_n)=\{L\}$* when $L=+\infty$ and $\{a_n\}$ is unbounded and does not converge to $L$.

This series should be solidly defined (that is, no "every $k$-th member is a random number").

*($PL$ being the set of partial limits - limits of converging sub-sequences of $\{a_n\}$)

Comment: I don't understand your second paragraph. You seem to be using $L$ in different ways. Can you state the second paragraph more clearly?

Comment: $L$ is just +$\infty$. That's just the way the question was formalized. Not to be confused with $PL(a_n)$ which is the series of partial limits of $a_n$. Again its just the way it has been written.

Comment: Yes but why use the same $L$ in$PL?$$\,$

Comment: idk, $PL(a_n)$ is just the notation he uses for a set of partial limits of $a_n$. You can call it $P$ if you'd like, or use $a$ instead of $L$ or just write $\infty$ and not bother.

Comment: By the very definition of convergence to $+\infty$, if $(a_n)$ doesn't converge to $+\infty$, then there is an $M$ and a subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ such that $a_{n_k} \leqslant M$ for all $k$. The sequence $(a_{n_k})$ then has a convergent (to a real number or to $-\infty$) subsequence, so the initial sequence $(a_n)$ has a partial limit different from $+\infty$ if it doesn't converge to $+\infty$.

Comment: Sorry Daniel, didn't see your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a_n$ is a real sequence whose only subsequential limit is $\infty,$ then $a_n\to \infty$ must hold. Proof sketch: Show that if $a_n\to \infty$ fails, then there exists a finite $M$ such that $a_n<M$ for infinitely many $n.$  Thus there is a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ lying in $(-\infty,M].$ Any such subsequence will itself have a subsequential limit in $[-\infty,M].$

Comment: So it's the last leap that we weren't shown. What I did know was that a bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence (Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem). So I guess you can prove that every sequence with an upper (or lower) bound has a subsequence that converges to a finite number or -$\infty$ (or $\infty$)?

Comment: How would such a proof go? We proved Bolzano-Weirestrass theorem using Cantors intersection theorem and nested intervals - how would that work with a semi-open infinite interval? I guess the teacher just wanted us to break our heads to arrive at this conclusion.

Comment: If $b_n$ is a sequence in $(-\infty,M]$ then either it is not bounded below by a finite number, or it is. In the first case there must be a subsequence $\to -\infty;$ in the second case, the sequence lies in $[a,b]$ for some real $a,b$ and B-W shows there is a convergent subsequence.